# 'user_birthday' not found in GraphUser - android facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

Permission was set in Facebook application dashboard to access user_birthday. In application user_birthday permission is listed in permission request.

```
 request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_work_history"));
```

In the JSON response after connecting with facebook, the tag firstname, middlename, lastname, email,and id was output but the json has no birthday tag. What have i missed

```
  Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser graphUser, Response response) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "LoggedInUser:" + graphUser);
                    Log.i(TAG, "LoggedInUser_Id:" + graphUser.getId());
                    Log.i(TAG, "LoggedInUser_First:" + graphUser.getFirstName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "LoggedInUser_Middle:" + graphUser.getMiddleName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "LoggedInUser_Last:" + graphUser.getLastName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "LoggedInUser_Email:" + graphUser.asMap().get("email"));
                    Log.e(TAG, "LoggedInUser_BIRTHDAY:" +  graphUser.asMap().get("user_birthday"));

                    String email = (String) graphUser.asMap().get("email");
                    if(email==null || email.isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Failed to get facebook credentials",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        editEmail.setText(email);

                    firstName = graphUser.getFirstName();
                    lastName  = graphUser.getLastName();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    String email = object
                                            .optString("email");
                                    String dob = object
                                            .optString("birthday");
                                    // user_id = object.optString("id");
                                    String name = object.optString("name");
                                    Log.d("fb detail", "" + email + " "
                                            + name + " " + dob);
                                    new LoginAsynTask(context).execute(
                                            "social", name, email, dob,
                                            object.optString("first_name"),
                                            object.optString("last_name"));
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + email,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters
                            .putString("fields",
                                    "id,name, email, birthday,gender,first_name,last_name");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Tried. Cannot resolved symbol GraphRequest. Can you explain what is happening please

Comment: can you p[lease tell me sdk version of facebook library. Please download facebook sdk 4.5.1 from   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android.

Comment: I am using com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0.  I found the bug, i did not set birthday tag in fields params. thank you :)